# Unable to delete a RDS-mysql snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[image]

**RDS:** my-sql

**What am I trying to achieve:**
 Trying to delete a RDS snapshot through CLI.

**What command did I use:**
 aws rds delete-db-snapshot --db-snapshot-identifier test

**Error Message:**
An error occurred (DBSnapshotNotFound) when calling the DeleteDBSnapshot operation:DBSnapshot not found: test

**Does it work with other CLI commands:**
Yes

**CLI Version :**
  Latest,updated just 2 days ago

**Is the snapshot in available mode:** 
 yes

Comment: Does aws rds describe-db-snapshots actually show the 'test' snapshot? Are you running against the correct region?

Comment: yes it does list 2 snap shots

Comment: Odd, it works fine here. I see the symptoms you describe if I re-run the command *after* deleting the test snapshot, but that's to be expected.

Comment: I just added a screen shot, anyhow both the instances are for test and educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the snapshot identifier when deleting snapshots. You have been mistakenly providing the DB instance identifier ('test').

By the way, 'true' and 'false' are probably bad choices of name for a snapshot identifier.

Comment: goodness !! thanks for that @jarmod. I realised what mistake I had made. Actually, when I wanted to delete the RDS instance through CLI, it didn't allow me to delete it until I give a true or false to the snapshot. I think that's where I made a mistake by naming the snapshot as true/false. That was a very good catch. Thanks again !! that resolved my issue.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's correct so that others know the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

1. Is test snapshot Manual or Automatic ?
2. Is your CLI accessing same AWS Account as your AWS Console. Probably good idea would be that firstly on CLI try to LIST all snapshots.

Comment: Hi Deepak, 1. it got created when I deleted my RDS instance. 2. I tried listing it with the command "describe-db-snapshots" and I could see both my snapshots

Comment: not sure whats going on there.. can u try deleting using AWS console. Other option is to create AWS support ticket

Comment: hi deepak , thanks for your input , @jarmod's answer helped me to fix the issue .